# forkJoin on two inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two input fields, **Street address** and **Zipcode**, which each of them emit it's value on keyup as Subject (Angular's event emitter).

I want to have both of the emitter values valid before calling an API end point using them.

First observable, **Street address**:

```
this.searchableComponent.value
            .do((value: any) => {
                if (value.length < this.MINIMAL_LENGTH_FOR_SEARCH) {
                    this.suggestions = [];
                }
            })
            .filter(() => this._zipcodeModel !== undefined && this._zipcodeModel.city.length > 0)
            .filter((value: any) => value.length >= this.MINIMAL_LENGTH_FOR_SEARCH)
            .debounceTime(this.DEBOUNCE_TIME_IN_MS)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .do(() => console.log('ready street address'))
```

Second observable **Zipcode**:

```
this.zipcodeInput.value
        .filter((value: string) => {
            const pattern = new RegExp(US_ZIPCODE);

            return pattern.test(value);
        })
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .mergeMap((zipcode: string) => this.addressService.lookup(zipcode))
        .map((zipcodeModel: ZipcodeModel) => this._zipcodeModel = zipcodeModel)
        .do(() => console.log('ready zipcode'))
```

The simple `forkJoin` to test (same implementation as combineLatest attempt):

```
forkJoin(this.searchableComponent.value, this.zipcodeInput.value)
            .subscribe((results: any) => {
                console.log(results)
            })
```

I tried using `forkJoin` on two of the observables, though none of them observables seems to emit anything.
When attempting to use `combineLatest` after the first observable was valid and completed, the combination of them completed on every emit, even if invalid, of the 2nd observable.

What is the right way to achieve completion of multiple observers when all are completed?

Comment: Try forkjoin the whole stream other than just .value

Comment: .value is the stream, it's a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject).

Comment: `forkJoin` won't emit until all of its source observables complete.

Comment: Both inputs contain valid values, none of them emits though (the console.log calls doesn't yield)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using `withLatestFrom`.

By adding `.withLatestFrom(this.zipcodeInput.value)` to the Street address observable I've manage to create the dependency I desired.

Still can't figure why `forkJoin` didn't do the trick.

Comment: [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) does not work because forkJoin only emits after all the source observables `complete`. The source do not complete, they are just emitting values on keyup